# What plugins are installed in ckeditor for primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, ckeditor

Im using primefaces/ckeditor and experiencing some issues with performance on large amounts of text under IE11 (this doesnt happen under Firefox)

I am wanting to test the impact of removing some plugins/extensions - but cant find a list of whats installed by default.

I suspect the list is defined under -

https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/resources-ckeditor/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/ckeditor/plugins

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Yes, seems right... but always better to ask questions like this on the PF(PFE) forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t understand why this was elected to close – but the answer can be found under build config -

https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/resources-ckeditor/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/ckeditor/build-config.js

You can see the selected plugins if you follow the link listed under build-config -

http://ckeditor.com/builder/e6b8a045f8f984a69463975ca3e6524a

Comment: _"I don’t understand why this was elected to close"_: Since it is not a 'coding' problem but something that can be seen and tried... (but that is my opinion) Removed it btw...